# Extract domains from one column while keeping other columns

Tags: regex, grep

I have a file with three columns that looks like that:

```
0       1612291061      http://www.staropolska.pl/
0       1612450417      http://m.kerygma.pl/
6831926761338023936     1612171787      http://www.kerygma.pl/hermeneutyka-biblijna/377-ksiegi-starego-testamentu-mini-streszczenie
6867871457052077056     1612534199      http://www.kerygma.pl/katechizm-kkk/kkk-iv-modlitwa/538-kkk-2558-2565
```

I want to extract domains from the third column whilst keeping the first two columns, so I want to have a file that looks like that:

```
0       1612291061      http://www.staropolska.pl
0       1612450417      http://m.kerygma.pl
6831926761338023936     1612171787      http://www.kerygma.pl
6867871457052077056     1612534199      http://www.kerygma.pl
```

So far I am able to extract domains using grep:

```
cat file.txt | grep -Eo '(http|https)://[^/"]+'
```

but this gives me only domains from third column:

```
http://www.staropolska.pl
http://m.kerygma.pl
http://www.kerygma.pl
http://www.kerygma.pl
```

without printing the first two.

Comment: Since you got `-o` switch, your regex needs to start from the beginning of the line, ie. add `^.*` to it. `man grep`: _Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to allow `grep` regex to match anything before `https?://`:

```sh
grep -Eo '.*[[:blank:]]https?://[^/"]+' file

0       1612291061      http://www.staropolska.pl
0       1612450417      http://m.kerygma.pl
6831926761338023936     1612171787      http://www.kerygma.pl
6867871457052077056     1612534199      http://www.kerygma.pl
```

**RegEx Explained:**

- `.*`: Match 0 or more of any characters
- `[[:blank:]]`: Match one space or tab character
- `https?`: Match `https` or `http`
- `://`: Match `://`
- `[^/"]+`: Match 1+ of any character that is not a `/` and not a `"`

**Alternatively**, you may try this `sed` as well:

```
sed -E 's~([[:blank:]]https?://[^/"]+).*~\1~' file
```

Answer (score 7):

Another option is `cut`, using `/` as delimiter:

```
$ cat file.txt | cut -d '/' -f 1-3
0       1612291061      http://www.staropolska.pl
0       1612450417      http://m.kerygma.pl
6831926761338023936     1612171787      http://www.kerygma.pl
6867871457052077056     1612534199      http://www.kerygma.pl
```

Answer (score 6):

With your shown samples in `awk`, could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/.*http[s]?:\/\/[^/]*/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/.*http[s]?:\/\/[^/]*/){    ##Using match function to match regex from starting to till http/https:// till next / here.
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)    ##Printing sub string of matched regex here.
}
' Input_file                         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option using gawk and gensub and use the capture group `\\1` in the replacement:

```
gawk '{
  print gensub(/(https?:\/\/[^/"]+).*/, "\\1", "g", $0);  
}
' file
```

Output

```
0       1612291061      http://www.staropolska.pl
0       1612450417      http://m.kerygma.pl
6831926761338023936     1612171787      http://www.kerygma.pl
6867871457052077056     1612534199      http://www.kerygma.pl
```